# Reduce image resolution/size just to show as preview

Tags: javascript, html, css

Currently, I'm having the high resolution images on the server. When displaying on the webpage, it takes so long to load the images because of their huge file size (about 10 MB).
I am thinking to display the image as preview (low resolution images) so that the loading time will be improved.
Can I use JavaScript to reduce the image size/resolution "on the fly" to display the table of images? I meant "on the fly" because I don't want to create and store the images for preview only.

Comment: Client-side JavaScript? Think about it for three seconds ... what would that JS need in the first place to be able to create a smaller version of that image? Right, the large original ... so you would need to send that to the client anyway, meaning in regard to the amount of data to be send and time that takes you gain exactly ... nothing.

Answer (score 3):

The javascript piece executed by the client will still have to download the full resolution image, resize it, then serve it. Let the server do the resizing and serve the thumbnail.